# check for a JSON string inside of a larger string in PHP

Tags: php, json, regex

Here is an example of a log file entry:

```
[22-Aug-2017 16:19:58 America/New_York] WP_Community_Events::maybe_log_events_response: Valid response received. Details: {"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress.org\/events\/1.0\/","request_args":{"body":{"number":5,"ip":"192.168.99.0","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"America\/New_York"}},"response_code":200,"response_body":{"location":{"ip":"47.197.97.47"},"events":"5 events trimmed."}}
```

The `{"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress....` portion is valid JSON, but obviously the entire string itself (the log entry line) isn't. I'm hitting a wall with a way to essentially pull out that JSON without messing up any other part of the string.

Comment: Looks like you can just cut everything before the first brace, and everything after the last brace.

Comment: JSON is coming after `Details:` I suppose. So that's a hint.

Comment: this was an _example_. it won't always have "details" in front (or anything else for that matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all the JSON and store it into an array like so:

```
$text = '[22-Aug-2017 16:19:58 America/New_York] WP_Community_Events::maybe_log_events_response: Valid response received. Details: {"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress.org\/events\/1.0\/","request_args":{"body":{"number":5,"ip":"192.168.99.0","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"America\/New_York"}},"response_code":200,"response_body":{"location":{"ip":"47.197.97.47"},"events":"5 events trimmed."}}';

preg_match_all('/\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}/x', $text, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress.org\/events\/1.0\/","request_args":{"body":{"number":5,"ip":"192.168.99.0","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"America\/New_York"}},"response_code":200,"response_body":{"location":{"ip":"47.197.97.47"},"events":"5 events trimmed."}}
)
```

You can read up more from:
[Extracting the JSON string from given text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995025/4739175)

OR if you want the opposite and remove the JSON out and keep the string then you can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do this:

```
$text = '[22-Aug-2017 16:19:58 America/New_York] WP_Community_Events::maybe_log_events_response: Valid response received. Details: {"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress.org\/events\/1.0\/","request_args":{"body":{"number":5,"ip":"192.168.99.0","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"America\/New_York"}},"response_code":200,"response_body":{"location":{"ip":"47.197.97.47"},"events":"5 events trimmed."}}';

$cleantext = preg_replace('~\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}~', '', $text);

echo $cleantext;
```

Credit from [PHP: How to extract JSON strings out of a string dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211157/4739175)

This yields:

```
[22-Aug-2017 16:19:58 America/New_York] WP_Community_Events::maybe_log_events_response: Valid response received. Details:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the start and end of the the json object and decode it. If there isn't a json decode error then you're good. This assumes that the characters `{` and `}` are only used in the json body.

```
function checkIfStringHasValidJson($string)
{
    $start = strpos($string, '{');
    $end = strrpos($string, '}');
    $json = substr($string, $start, $end);
    json_decode($json);
    return json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

Comment: wanted to say this also worked, but the preg_match_all will get all of them (if more than one exist)

Comment: @Norcross Makes sense, I assume there was just one object and was intentionally keeping it light. Glad you have a solution!

Comment: Actually it is $end + 1

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove everything from the string before and including the given substring of "Details:":

```
$s = '[22-Aug-2017 16:19:58 America/New_York] WP_Community_Events::maybe_log_events_response: Valid response received. Details: {"api_url":"https:\/\/api.wordpress.org\/events\/1.0\/","request_args":{"body":{"number":5,"ip":"192.168.99.0","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"America\/New_York"}},"response_code":200,"response_body":{"location":{"ip":"47.197.97.47"},"events":"5 events trimmed."}}';
$out = str_replace('Details: ', '', strstr($s, 'Details:'));
echo var_export(json_decode($out));
```