# Extract json object from wget request

Tags: json, regex, extract

I want to do with php exactly the opposite of what James Nine was asking in [PHP: How to extract JSON strings out of a string dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210714/php-how-to-extract-json-strings-out-of-a-string-dump).

That is to keep the json object(s) out from a large output from a wget request. I can't figure out what the regex should be, basically negate

```
~\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}~
```

Comment: What would the desired output of an example be?

Comment: If you have the match you can replace it with an empty string. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I tried this, with a preg_replace, but not working, even with escaping the text. An example is the output of wget -q -O - https://edmo.seadatanet.org/report/4912

Comment: So your question is more like "How to remove json object from wget request result" ?

Comment: I have found the right regex here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string which solved my problem.